# Where can I find the directory structure and important files paths explained?

Tags: filesystem

Server only therefore console only. I assume it must be somewhere in /usr/share/doc/ ?

http://www.pathname.com/fhs/ (Filesystem Hierarchy Standard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shell command to execute:

```
man hier
```

Answer (score 2):

For a more detailed documentation, in particular, on Ubuntu systems, install the following package:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-policy
```

And see this document:

```
/usr/share/doc/ubuntu-policy/fhs/fhs-2.3.txt.gz
```