# What Does the Mount used for ?what does they mean?

Tags: system-installation, mount

I have dual boot many time normally i use  `/` As **/** is the Top of hierarchical model of OS 
what does other like  :-

/boot

/home

/tmp

/usr

/var

/srv

/opt

/urs/local

used for ? What are meaning of these  ?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to understand the Ubuntu file system layout?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/138547/how-to-understand-the-ubuntu-file-system-layout)

Comment: Also see http://askubuntu.com/q/427379/158442 and http://askubuntu.com/q/488544/158442

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roughly speaking these all are basically different directories of your system.
Each directory is created for different purposes. For example

```
/boot - To store boot related files, grub config files etc

/home - user home directory all users data is stored under this directory
```

and so on..you can get the complete list from google.

The root directory i.e. `/` directory is the parent of all these directories.The `/` directory contains all these directories.

While installing if you select `/` as a mount point then a single partition is created for `/` directory and hence all these directories will be created in that partition but sometimes it is preferred to create separate partitions for some directories like `/boot`, `/home` etc. because it helps while reinstalling or updating the system.

Hence if you want to create the separate partition for /boot you just create 3 patitions(1 swap, 1 for / and 1 for /boot) and for 3rd partition you select /boot as the mount point.

I hope this clears your doubts!