# Can we have more user friendly directory names?

Tags: directory, naming

Like in the picture shown below:

[image]

Comment: No, we cannot and the vast majority of us wouldn't want that. User "friendlyness" is a very subjective matter.

Comment: You can't rename system folders. but for easier access, you can create links to them with optional name and path.

Comment: @ChanganAuto, I am a new user of Linux and this is my first impression.
I like the open source idea, but with this naming convention I don't like it.

Comment: Калоян Велков - this directory naming convention has a 50 year old history behind it, so it's not going to change overnight.

Comment: The naming convention for the user space is very similar to a well known proprietary OS. Users typically don't need to view/access anything else in the system so this is a moot point. Do not confuse "user friendly" with "familiarity", a typical newbie mistake. At some point you were familiarized with something you now want to apply somewhere else. That only make it more familiar to you, not more user friendly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can I find the directory structure and important files paths explained?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/427379/where-can-i-find-the-directory-structure-and-important-files-paths-explained)

Answer (score 4):

No, not on the system level.

But you could make your own folder on the desktop that contain links to the folders shown above, with the names you choose yourself.

In a folder with symlinks, you can have it exactly as you want, without affecting the rest of the system directly.

Comment: Another option is to change Nautilus / Files manager with alias's to user preference, even alias in different languages. Such an enhancement to toggle view back and forth would benefit both the systems administrator and the end user.